# Postgresql: Rollbacks in shared objects

Tags: postgresql, rollback

We have PostgreSQL 15.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18), 64-bit on Virtual Machine (do not know which one).
Inside it has one db `prod_pg` with many schemes. Each scheme corresponds to java microservises which deployed in Kubernetes.

At some time number of rollbacks rises in many times (about 6k every 10 seconds) and stays at this level for days or weeks until db restart. Also CPU utilizing rises to about 25%. But there is no network activity increasing same time.

[image: Commits and Rollbacks Graph]

**Almost all rollbacks occurs in shared objects area** (datid = 0):

```
select *
from pg_stat_database;
```

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **datid** | 0 | 16390 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| **datname** | null | prod_pg | postgres | template0 | template1 |
| **numbackends** | 0 | 278 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| **xact_commit** | 1 | 39059077 | 1655562 | 20184 | 20204 |
| **xact_rollback** | **655708081** | 548 | 11 | 2 | 0 |
| **blks_read** | 181 | 405426 | 606 | 115 | 193 |
| **blks_hit** | 1973811072 | 7768298439 | 6960138 | 738681 | 739757 |
| **tup_returned** | 669951805 | 220238634249 | 93281938 | 8830048 | 8831773 |
| **tup_fetched** | 657302243 | 241988153 | 991397 | 142477 | 142907 |
| **tup_inserted** | 5279 | 1024943 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| **tup_updated** | 9 | 234555 | 202 | 7 | 8 |
| **tup_deleted** | 0 | 127745 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **conflicts** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **temp_files** | 0 | 3103 | 45917 | 0 | 0 |
| **temp_bytes** | 0 | 5563509216 | 87904801178 | 0 | 0 |
| **deadlocks** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **checksum_failures** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **checksum_last_failure** | null | null | null | null | null |
| **blk_read_time** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **blk_write_time** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **session_time** | 56748934679444.76 | 335112228024.794 | 1516089306326.44 | 1513973633442.82 | 82275.257 |
| **active_time** | 0 | 43830518.259 | 3860587.554 | 0 | 83.428 |
| **idle_in_transaction_time** | 0 | 142470966.389 | 1.448 | 0 | 0 |
| **sessions** | 0 | 183919 | 73 | 0 | 1 |
| **sessions_abandoned** | 0 | 1037 | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| **sessions_fatal** | 0 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| **sessions_killed** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **stats_reset** | null | null | null | null | null |

As far as I know there is no such jobs, which can lead to so many rollbacks for so long time. At least all business processes works fine and no one complains.

Also we have logs enabled with following parameters:

```
log_statement 
---------------
all

log_min_duration_statement 
----------------------------
5s

log_min_duration_sample 
-------------------------
-1

log_statement_sample_rate 
---------------------------
1

log_transaction_sample_rate 
-----------------------------
0

log_min_error_statement 
-------------------------
error
```

But in logs there is no records with "ROLLBACK" word.

**What can cause so many rollbacks in many times? Or how to find cause?**

#### Additional information:

When I make query

```
select *
from pg_stat_activity
order by state
```

There are about 260 simultaneous processes. All are idle, except mine and other with query

```
START_REPLICATION SLOT "pgstandby1" 0/FD000000 TIMELINE 1
```

So it is not look like one of processes causes rollbacks - since it is about 600 rollbacks/sec at least some times another one process should be active (not idle).

And I found that in `pg_stat_sys_tables` columns `idx_scan` and `idx_tup_fetched` for `relname = 'pg_authid'` has surprisingly close value to `xact_rollback` in `pg_stat_database`:

```
select *
from pg_stat_sys_tables
order by idx_scan desc
```

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **relid** | 1260 | 1262 | 2964 | 2615 | 2610 | 1259 |
| **schemaname** | pg_catalog | pg_catalog | pg_catalog | pg_catalog | pg_catalog | pg_catalog |
| **relname** | pg_authid | pg_database | pg_db_role_setting | pg_namespace | pg_index | pg_class |
| **seq_scan** | 354931 | 975778 | 0 | 175384 | 80 | 241074 |
| **seq_tup_read** | 8544411 | 3903060 | 0 | 701535 | 1690 | 91130182 |
| **idx_scan** | **656064477** | 998702 | 992355 | 526810 | 199154 | 135221 |
| **idx_tup_fetch** | **656064467** | 998701 | 178996 | 526738 | 24235 | 48330 |
| **n_tup_ins** | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **n_tup_upd** | 3 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 145 |
| **n_tup_del** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **n_tup_hot_upd** | 3 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 17 |
| **n_live_tup** | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 412 |
| **n_dead_tup** | 3 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 130 |
| **n_mod_since_analyze** | 6 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 4 |
| **n_ins_since_vacuum** | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **last_vacuum** | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| **last_autovacuum** | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| **last_analyze** | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| **last_autoanalyze** | null | null | null | null | null | 2023-12-27 10:09:50.795831 +00:00 |
| **vacuum_count** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **autovacuum_count** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **analyze_count** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **autoanalyze_count** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

And this values continue to grow for the roughly same amount.

Yesterday was (data from tables above):

```
xact_rollback 655708081
idx_scan 656064477
idx_tup_fetch 656064467
```

Today values:

```
xact_rollback 709413257
idx_scan 709794594
idx_tup_fetch 709794584
```

We didn't try anything. Since we do not understand the cause. Only db restart during maintenance helps for some time.

There is and idea to restart java microservices one by one and see if it help. But this not very good idea since it will cause troubles in others people work.

**Edit:**
Today result of following query:

```
select *
from pg_stat_database
where datid = 0;
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| **datid** | 0 |
| **datname** | null |
| **numbackends** | 0 |
| **xact_commit** | 1 |
| **xact_rollback** | **933428800** |
| **blks_read** | 211 |
| **blks_hit** | 2809216719 |
| **tup_returned** | 952245139 |
| **tup_fetched** | 935574717 |
| **tup_inserted** | 7363 |
| **tup_updated** | 9 |
| **tup_deleted** | 0 |
| **conflicts** | 0 |
| **temp_files** | 0 |
| **temp_bytes** | 0 |
| **deadlocks** | 0 |
| **checksum_failures** | 0 |
| **checksum_last_failure** | null |
| **blk_read_time** | 0 |
| **blk_write_time** | 0 |
| **session_time** | 56748934679444.76 |
| **active_time** | 0 |
| **idle_in_transaction_time** | 0 |
| **sessions** | 0 |
| **sessions_abandoned** | 0 |
| **sessions_fatal** | 0 |
| **sessions_killed** | 0 |
| **stats_reset** | null |

Comment: A rollback that is not caused by the client disconnecting or an explicit `ROLLBACK` is probably caused by an error. With the default settings, errors get logged, so look in the log file for errors.

Comment: I checked the logs (11 minute log from 2024-01-03 00:00:00 +06 to 2024-01-03 00:11:56 +06) . No `ERROR` or even `err` words in there.

Comment: No idea how you can end up with a rollback without being connected to a database.

Comment: I'm connected to database. And there about 260 another connections to database. In more detail in "Additional information" section of the question.

Comment: Still, I don't see how that could happen. How can there be a transaction when you are not connected to a database?

Comment: I'm connected to database. I'm making queries to `pg_stat_database` and other tables.
Why do you think that I'm not connected to the database? And why does that matter? There are other about 260 processes/connections from java services.

Comment: I think it might help if you could add a transaction that produces the observed statistics increase for `dbid` 0 to the question.

Comment: Because if you are connected to a database, the statistics will be counted there.

Comment: I don't understand you. What transaction do you mean?
The one, that shows about 6k rollbacks on graph?
Or some other? May be you could provide query example of transaction you mean.

Comment: I think we are talking past each other. All I am saying is that I cannot imagine what could cause these statistics. Consequently, I cannot help you. Particularly if there is nothing in the PostgreSQL log file.

Comment: @user23189428 Have you found the solution? Looks like im experiencing similar behaviour. At least that xact_rollback is increasing, application is running smoothly, i even tried log_statement = 'all' but no entries with word ROLLBACK were found

Comment: @smrndmname, we made connection logging like this log_connections = true,
log_disconnections = true, log_hostname = true. And saw in the logs enormous amount of connections with client=local. It means that some client tries to connect. Also we had to restart db for other reasons. Since then no massive rollback. Kinda suspicious, so we don't what client caused so much connections.